# When selecting an option in the form, I get "0: Object" instead of an object

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have separated component for select input in form:

**.html**

```
<div class="row mb-3">
  <label class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-form-label">{{title}}</label>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
    <select class="form-select"
            formControlName="{{formControllerName}}"
            (change)="onChangeSelectOption(formControllerName, $event)">
      <option *ngFor="let option of selectionOptions" [ngValue]="option">
        {{ option.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
// import section...

@Component({...})
export class FormSelectComponent {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Input() formControllerName: string;
  @Input() selectedOption: IBuildingType | null;
  @Input() selectionOptions: IBuildingType[];

  onChangeSelectOption(formControlName: string, e: any) {
    this.getFormControl(formControlName)?.setValue(e.target.value, {
      onlySelf: true,
    });
  }

  getFormControl(name: string) {
    return this.form.get(name);
  }
}
```

When there are more than one selector, after selecting the second value, the previous one turns into a string (although it was an object) "N: Object".

Example (before choose option in first select), form values:

```
{    ...
    "buildingType1": null,
    "buildingType2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Flat"
    },
    ...
}
```

Example (after choose option in first select), form values:

```
{    ...
    "buildingType1": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "House"
    },
    "buildingType2": "2: Object",
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you put a console.log(e.target.value) inside the onChangeSelectOption to see what type the log output has. i got the feeling youre not passing a string to the setValue function

Comment: Console output such info: https://imgur.com/a/UfXrGbu

Comment: a formControl is "two way binding". It's unnecessary use setValue!!! BTW, if you get some like "2:Object" is because (not in the code you show, It seems correct) you're using interpolation `{{ ` `}}` instead binding `[ ` `]`. If, e.g. you write `<option value={{variable}}>` variable is first convert to a string, if you use `<option [ngValue]="variable">` you get the value of the variable. If the variable is an object you see why the second way is the correct to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@Eliseo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8558186/eliseo)!

> a formControl is "two way binding". It's unnecessary use setValue!!!

I've removed `(change)="onChangeSelectOption(formControllerName, $event)"` and now it works.